# react-native TextInput clips text

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, textinput

I'm trying to create an expandable text view.  I've tried using the `onChangeContentSize` property of `TextInput`, but it doesn't update the width.  If I don't explicitly set the width, the content `TextInput` expands as I type, which is the desired behavior, but it starts to clip/obscure the text as it grows.

Hopefully the issue can be fixed with styling, but so far I haven't been able to. It's almost like I need be able to set an overflow prop that doesn't exist.

Code is:

```
  render() {

    console.log(this.state.width)
    let inputStyle = {
        color: '#fff',
        // width: this.state.width,
        fontSize: 60,
        lineHeight: 60,
        fontFamily: 'GT-Walsheim-Bold'
    }

      return (
        <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>{this.props.label}</Text>
          <TextInput
            secureTextEntry={this.props.secureTextEntry}
            placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
            autoCorrect={false}
            style={inputStyle}
            value={this.props.value}
            onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText}
            autoFocus={true}
            autoCapitalize={this.props.capitalize}
          />
        </View>
      );
  }

const styles = {

  labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 36,
    fontFamily: 'GT-Walsheim-Bold'
  },
  containerStyle: {
    height: 200,
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
};
```

Dev Env: OSX 10.12
react-native: 16.3.1
react: 0.55.4
platform: Android

See images attached:

Before typing:
[image]

After typing:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much tinkering, it turns out the clipping is related to the custom font.  Substituting the font solves the problem.  It seems the expanding TextInput's default behavior when no width is set is doing exactly what I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

So one of the hackish ways is to set width via the state, suppose initially width is around 20 pixel(depending upon your font) and then for each addition of character, you will add 16px(depending upon your font) to the width.

Example:-

```js
          <TextInputCustom
              style={[{
                fontSize: 34,
                width:this.state.flexibleWidth// intially 27px
                textAlign: 'center',
                fontWeight: "bold",
                fontStyle: "normal",
                letterSpacing: -0.31,
                color: Colors.BLACK}]}
              isUnderlineRequired={false}
              onChangeText={(text) => this.checkInteger(text)}
              placeholder={"0"}
              returnKeyLabel="done"
              keyboardType="numeric"
              maxLength={10}
              value={this.state.amount + ""}
              ref={"input"}
            />
```

checkInteger function

```js
  checkInteger = (text) => {
    let len = text.length
  
    this.setState((state) => {
        return {
          amount: text,
          flexibleWidth: (len * 16) + 27
          error:'
        }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd tried something similar to this, but unfortunately I'm entering text and not integers, so there's no reliable way to add to the width based on each character, so it ends up being a bit random seeing as there's no reliable way to measure the width of the text

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, and if you pass a `<Text />` (with your styling + font of course) component as the child of `<TextInput />` it should work.

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  render () {

    console.log(this.state.width)
    let textStyle = {
        color: '#fff',
        // width: this.state.width,
        fontSize: 60,
        lineHeight: 60,
        fontFamily: 'GT-Walsheim-Bold'
    }

    return (
      <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
        <Text style={styles.labelStyle}>{this.props.label}</Text>
        <TextInput
          secureTextEntry={this.props.secureTextEntry}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          autoCorrect={false}
          style={inputStyle}
          onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText}
          autoFocus={true}
          autoCapitalize={this.props.capitalize}
        >
          <Text>{this.props.value}</Text>
        </TextInput>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 36,
    fontFamily: 'GT-Walsheim-Bold'
  },
  containerStyle: {
    height: 200,
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
};
```

Comment: You won't be able to select text or move cursor with this method